# chaining AND EXISTS/AND NOT EXISTS in SQL

Tags: sql

So I have this thing I have to do in SQL and I don't know why the logic is eluding me.

Say I have a query that already exists and works:

```
SET someValue = 1 --let's say someValue is 0 before this query
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a_tbl WHERE valueA = a_tbl.id)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b_tbl WHERE valueB = b_tbl.id)
```

and now I want to add another exists statement such that if

```
SELECT 1 FROM b_tbl WHERE valueB = b_tbl.id
```

returns a row (aka it's true) then another SELECT statement has to return a row too such as:

```
SELECT 1 from c_tbl WHERE valueC = c_tbl.id
```

Thus I someValue to be set to 1 if either valueB <> b_tbl.id or valueC <> c_tbl.id

Here was my first guess:

```
SET someValue = 1 --let's say someValue is 0 before this query
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a_tbl WHERE valueA = a_tbl.id)
AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b_tbl WHERE valueB = b_tbl.id)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from c_tbl WHERE valueC = c_tbl.id))
```

but that doesn't seem to work when valueB <> b_tbl.id (i.e. someValue isn't set to 1 when it shouldn't be)

Hopefully this makes sense, I know I probably didn't explain it well.

Comment: Can edit the question with sample data and expected output

Comment: Well, if `valueB <> b_tbl.id` then it `NOT EXISTS` so it'll return true. But if `valueC = c_tbl.id` then it'll be false. If you want either to be true, shouldn't you be using an `OR` operator?

Comment: Also, could you make a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Boolean algebra. Your current query is this:

```
valueA = a_tble.id and valueB <> b_tble.id
```

and, if I'm reading your requirements correctly, you want it to be this:

```
valueA = a_tble.id and (valueB <> b_tble.id or valueC <> c_tble.id)
```

which translates into:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a_tbl WHERE valueA = a_tbl.id)
    AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b_tbl WHERE valueB = b_tbl.id)
     OR  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from c_tbl WHERE valueC = c_tbl.id))
```

Comment: yep, that's it. Not sure why I was getting confused by the logic

Comment: If there is anything from college I use on an almost daily basis, it's Boolean logic and truth tables. Especially when an IF statement grows over time. Translate it into Boolean expression with A, B, C etc., see if it can be simplified. Maybe plug it into a truth table and extract the most simple expression. Saves hours.